# Suppose $\frac{ x+2}{ x-2} = i $

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having some hard time with this question:

> Suppose $\frac{z+2}{z-2} = i$. Find $z$ in the form $a+bi$ where $a,b\in \Bbb R$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\frac{z+2}{z-2} $= $i$

you will get $z+2=iz−2i$ or $ z(1−i) = -2(1+i)$

$z = -2\frac{(1+i)}{(1-i)} $

$z= -2\frac{(1+i)(1+i)}{2} $ {I have just rationalised it}

$z= -(1+i)(1+i)$ ,i.e, $ z= -2i$.

Answer (score 1):

Use [componendo and dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/) to obtain $$\frac{2z}{4} = \frac{i+1}{i-1}$$
Which gives, $$z = \frac{2(i+1)}{i-1}$$`
Multiplying by $(i+1)$ in numerator and denominator to obtain the result in the form $a + ib$,
$$z = \frac{2(i+1)^2}{(i-1)(i+1)} = \frac{2(2i)}{-2} = -2i$$
where I have used $i^2 = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

From $\frac{z+2}{z-2} = i$ you get $z+2=iz-2i$, hence $z(1-i)= ??$ $ \to $ your turn !

Answer (score 0):

let $z=a+ib$ then , 
$z+2/z-2=i\ \implies a+ib+2=ia-b-2i$

$\implies a+b=-2\ \text{and}\ b-a=-2 $

$\implies 2b=-4$ and $b=-2\ \text{and}\ a=0$

hence z=-2i

Answer (score 0):

Look at a general example, when $\exists\space\text{z}_1\space\wedge\space\exists\space\text{z}_2\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\exists\space\text{n}\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\frac{\text{z}_1+\text{n}}{\text{z}_1-\text{n}}=\text{z}_2$$

And we want to solve $\text{z}_1$.

---

First we look at the fraction:

$$\frac{\text{z}_1+\text{n}}{\text{z}_1-\text{n}}=\frac{\left(\text{z}_1+\text{n}\right)\cdot\overline{\text{z}_1-\text{n}}}{\left(\text{z}_1-\text{n}\right)\cdot\overline{\text{z}_1-\text{n}}}=\frac{\left(\text{z}_1+\text{n}\right)\cdot\overline{\text{z}_1-\text{n}}}{\left|\text{z}_1-\text{n}\right|^2}$$

Now, we look at the denominator:

$$\left|\text{z}_1-\text{n}\right|^2=\left|\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]i\right)-\text{n}\right|^2=\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\text{n}\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]$$

And to the numerator:

$$\left(\text{z}_1+\text{n}\right)\cdot\overline{\text{z}_1-\text{n}}=\left(\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]i\right)+\text{n}\right)\cdot\overline{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]i\right)-\text{n}}=$$
$$\left(\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]i\right)+\text{n}\right)\cdot\left(\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]i\right)-\text{n}\right)=$$
$$\Re^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\text{n}^2-2\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]\text{n}i$$

So, we get:

1. $$\Re\left[\frac{\text{z}_1+\text{n}}{\text{z}_1-\text{n}}\right]=\frac{\Re^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\text{n}^2}{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\text{n}\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]}$$
2. $$\Im\left[\frac{\text{z}_1+\text{n}}{\text{z}_1-\text{n}}\right]=-\frac{2\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]\text{n}}{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\text{n}\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]}$$

We can set-up a system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\Re^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\text{n}^2}{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\text{n}\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]}=\Re\left[\text{z}_2\right]\\
\\
-\frac{2\Im\left[\text{z}_1\right]\text{n}}{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}_1\right]-\text{n}\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}_1\right]}=\Im\left[\text{z}_2\right]
\end{cases}
$$